# How can I continuously cycle through an array list (from the end reverting back to the start) using an event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

The function below cycles through an array (summaryList) using the ctrl  left/right arrow keypress; but when it reaches 'item6' the array ends. I'm having trouble setting the function where after the last item in the array is reached, the next keypress will start back at the first item (index 0)

```
var summaryList;
    summaryList = [
            'item0',
            'item1',
            'item2',
            'item3',
            'item4',
            'item5',
            'item6',
        ];


// Hold reference to the currently focused position
var currentPosition = 0;

// Maximum position we can navigate to is the last item in the summary list
var maxFocusablePosition = summaryList.length - 1;

// Utility function to focus a given position value
function focusPosition(position) {
console.log("focus position is called");
$('#' + summaryList[position]).focus().css('border', 'yellow');
};


 $(document).keydown(function (event) { 
        if (event.which === 37 && event.ctrlKey) { 
            currentPosition > 0 ? currentPosition-- : maxFocusablePosition; 
            console.log('left');
        } 

        if (event.which === 39 && event.ctrlKey) {
            currentPosition < maxFocusablePosition ? currentPosition++ : 0; 
            console.log('right');
        } 

        focusPosition(currentPosition); 
    });

}
```

Comment: you have an additional closing brace here `}` so where is the start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var summaryList;
    summaryList = [
            'item0',
            'item1',
            'item2',
            'item3',
            'item4',
            'item5',
            'item6',
        ];

// Hold reference to the currently focused position
var currentPosition = 0;

// Maximum position we can navigate to is the last item in the summary list
var maxFocusablePosition = summaryList.length - 1;

// Utility function to focus a given position value
function focusPosition(position) {
    alert(position+" = "+summaryList[position]);
    //$('#' + summaryList[position]).focus().css('border', 'yellow');
};


$(document).keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.which==37) {
        currentPosition = (currentPosition>0) ? parseInt(currentPosition)-1 : maxFocusablePosition; 
        //alert('left');
    }
    if (event.which==39) {
        currentPosition = (currentPosition<maxFocusablePosition) ? parseInt(currentPosition)+1 : 0; 
        //alert(currentPosition);
        //alert('right');
    } 
    focusPosition(currentPosition); 
});
```

certain modifications were done in order to achieve your requirement, everything works good, only one thing does faulty here, which is `currentPosition` var, which is not an int var, and you tried incrementing it, so convert `currentPosition` to int using `parseInt`, and your code works fine.

> **NOTE :** it is always recommended to use brackets while using shorter way of if and else statement EG. `(condition) ? statement : statement`

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/e54ax51j/1/

Comment: That's ternary operation and it's not a problem not having () around.

Comment: i knew that @Jai, i didn't say that, use of ternary operator is a mistake here, i just mentioned here as use of brackets is always better.

Comment: And one more thing if you know the value is a number then parsing is a overhead operation.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last:

```
 }
```

Which occurs after closing of key down event. That is resulting in an error.